# I'm getting an error <string>:149: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt while generating a list

Tags: python, numpy, sqrt

```
def ellipse(numPoints, genX=np.linspace, HALF_WIDTH=10, HALF_HEIGHT=6.5):
    xs = 10.*genX(-1,1,numPoints)
    ys = 6.5*np.sqrt(1-(xs**2))
    return(xs, ys, "-")
```

I am getting an error that states that an invalid value was encountered in a squareroot. I can't see what it is.

```
sqrt(0) = 0
6.5*sqrt(1- (-1**2)) = 0
```

They should work, but the y values are having problems, they are returning "nan"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting a warning <RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123766/i-am-getting-a-warning-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-sqrt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

probably `xs**2` returns a number `> 1` sqrt with negative number will return nan (not a number)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.sqrt(-1)
nan
```

If i am right numpy  provides complex numbers functionality which i think is the only way to represent sqrt(x) where x<0

Comment: There shouldn't be any values that are the squareroot of a negative number when i'm going from -1 to 1. nvm. edit* I see it now

Comment: I should have 6.5*sqrt(100-(xs**2))

Comment: also if you want numpy to give an error on such cases you can use `np.seterr(all='raise')` and would give `FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in sqrt` instead of `nan`. more info here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html#how-numpy-handles-numerical-exceptions