# I am getting a warning <RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt>

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, math

I am trying to run a quadratic equation in python. However, it keeps on giving me a warning

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np


a = 0.75 + (1.25 - 0.75)*np.random.randn(10000)
print(a)
b = 8 + (12 - 8)*np.random.randn(10000)
print(b)
c = -12 + 2*np.random.randn(10000)
print(c)
x0 = (-b - np.sqrt(b**2 - (4*a*c)))/(2 * a)
print(x0)
```

Comment: As per the output of variables a,b and c and my sample calculation. I should not get a -ve number for the value of b**2 - (4*a*c). Nonetheless, it is giving out some 'nan' values.

Comment: There is a negative number with value `-3.1107176892482471`  in `b**2 - (4*a*c)`. Actually, there are many

Comment: @MaroofG You definitely have negative values. See my answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is not 100% Python related. You can't calculate the square root of a negative number (when dealing with real numbers that is).

You didn't take any precautions for when `b**2 - (4*a*c)` is a negative number.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> np.sqrt(4)
2.0
>>> np.sqrt(-4)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
nan
```

Let's test if you have negative values:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a = 0.75 + (1.25 - 0.75) * np.random.randn(10000)
>>> b = 8 + (12 - 8) * np.random.randn(10000)
>>> c = -12 + 2 * np.random.randn(10000)
>>> 
>>> z = b ** 2 - (4 * a * c)
>>> print len([_ for _ in z if _ < 0])
71
```

Comment: Yup!!, it does generate -ve values. Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the random sample generator to "np.random.sample" and it works as expected. Appreciate your assistance DeepSpace and @dunder

Comment: But what if i do want it perform sqrt of negative numbers? what if i want it to return complex numbers. how do i do that?

Answer (score 11):

Square roots are not defined for strictly negative real numbers, and numpy will produce `nan` for negative inputs of "real" dtype `int`, `float`, and it's two special values `-np.inf` and `nan`.

However, square roots are defined for all *complex* dtype:

| **Sign** | **Data Type** | **E.g. (`x`)** | **`np.sqrt(x)`** | **Runtime Warning** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ➕ | Float/Int | `1.` / `1` | `1.` / `1` |  |
| ➕ | Complex | `1+0J` | `1` |  |
| ➕ | Infinity | `np.inf` | `np.inf` |  |
| ➖ | Float/Int | `-1.` / `-1` | `nan` | ⚠️ |
| ➖ | Complex | `-1+0j` | `1j` |  |
| ➖ | Infinity | `-np.inf` | `nan` | ⚠️ |
| N/A | NaN | `np.nan` | `nan` |  |

Answer (score 2):

If you're hoping to do complex analysis (working with imaginary numbers as defined by sqrt(-1)) you can import cmath and use cmath.sqrt(-1) instead of numpy.sqrt(-1).

For example, when I'm calculating the refractive index of materials from permittivity and permeability (by definition, j is involved), I'll write functions in python as such:

```
def n(f):
    y = cmath.sqrt(mu1f(f) - j*mu2f(f)) * (e1f(f) - j*e2f(f))
    return y.real
```

Where e1f etc. are previously defined interpolating functions, all of which are a function of incident frequency f. The y resultant is, in it of itself, a complex value, the complex index of refraction, but I'm oftentimes only interested in the real portion (the refractive index) so that is what is returned.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add an insight along with the above answers.
The `cmath` function always returns complex numbers but if you want a unified treatment of complex and float object I would recommend using `numpy.lib.scimath`.

**Note**: The `sqrt()` function in this is slower that that of the versions from `cmath` and `math` module but it has flexibility to return a complex object in the case of a negative argument and a float object otherwise