# Input other than negative numbers that may produce warning "invalid value" with numpy.sqrt?

Tags: python, numpy, absolute

I had a `np.sqrt()` snippet that didn't check for negative values, so I understandably got warnings. I thought I had fixed it, but I got one again:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  data_std = np.sqrt(np.absolute(data_std))
```

Are there any invalid numbers other than negative ones for `np.sqrt`?

Comment: Which version of NumPy?

Comment: @Dux `np.sqrt(np.nan)` returns `nan` and `np.sqrt(np.infty)` returns `inf`

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce the warning?  If so, a call to `print(np.absolute(data_std))` would give you the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting a warning <RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123766/i-am-getting-a-warning-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-sqrt)

Answer (score 0):

Square roots are not defined for negative real numbers, and numpy will produce `nan` for negative inputs of "real" dtype `int`, `float`, `-np.inf` (and `nan` itself).

However, square roots are defined for all *complex* numbers:

| dtype | example `x` | `np.sqrt(x)` | `RuntimeWarning` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Positive float | `1.` | `1.` |  |
| Positive int | `1` | `1` |  |
| Positive complex | `1+0J` | `1` |  |
| Negative float | `-1.` | `nan` | ⚠️ |
| Negative int | `-1` | `nan` | ⚠️ |
| Negative complex | `-1+0j` | `1j` |  |
|  | `np.inf` | `np.inf` |  |
|  | `np.inf` | `nan` | ⚠️ |
|  | `np.nan` | `nan` |  |